# Replacing a particular multiline pattern using awk

Tags: regex, awk

Below is my tab separated file:

```
$OC90$  BMPR2
TRA@    CANX
TRA@    HLA-B
TRG@    TRD@
AP2M1   $ZBTB8$
$ZBTB8$ $ZBTB8$
```

where first and second columns represent Gene Symbols. Some symbols are enclosed by $ and some by @ sign. How to remove these two symbols (@ and $) from file using awk.

Comment: Where is the code you have written, so that we can help you fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 awk 'gsub(/[@$]/,"") || 7' file
```

Comment: Is `7` your lucky number? :)

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` should do:

```
awk '{gsub(/\$|@/,"")}1' file
OC90    BMPR2
TRA     CANX
TRA     HLA-B
TRG     TRD
AP2M1   ZBTB8
ZBTB8   ZBTB8
```

Answer (score 1):

`tr` would be simpler here:  `tr -d '@$' < file`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{gsub(/\$/,"",$0); gsub(/@/,"",$0); print;}' inputfile
```